# Let $z$ be a complex number of maximum argument satisfying $|z-3|=\operatorname{Re}(z)$, then find $\operatorname{Re}(z)$.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number of maximum argument satisfying $|z-3|=\operatorname{Re}(z)$, then find $\operatorname{Re}(z)$.

I tried representing $z$ as $x+iy$ but it led to nowhere, please help.

**EDIT: Changed amplitude to argument, as there was confusion in terminology.**

Comment: Are you looking for the $z$ of smallest or largest modulus?

Comment: Largest I am sure.

Comment: That would be unbounded. Think of the modulus of points on the parabola.

Comment: Well, I would say that there are points with arbitrarily large real part.

Comment: Are you sure that it is points of maximum amplitude and not phase?

Comment: Yeah, the answer given is 3. Do you mean argument by 'phase'.

Comment: Either maximum phase or minimum amplitude make sense to me...

Comment: Or maximum argument... Yes, phase and argument are synonymous to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Representing $z$ that way should've lead you somewhere, because it tells you that $\sqrt{(x-3)^2 + y^2} = x$, which you can square and solve.

Comment: Well I got $x=\frac{9+y^2}{6}$ but I don't know what to do with the fact that z has max. amplitude

Comment: The number with the maximum amplitude is the one where the tangent to the graph of $x = \frac{y^2 + 9}6$ crosses the origin.

Comment: How does it give the max amplitude?

Comment: There are points of arbitrarily large magnitude that satisfy the equation?

Comment: Because if you take a line (with positive amplitude) that goes through the origin and intersects the graph twice, then any point on the graph between those points will have a larger amplitude. So if you want a line that goes through the origin and the point with the highest amplitude, it can't go through any other point on the graph, which means that the line must be tangent.

Comment: @copper.hat We're talking amplitude, not magnitude. Angle against the real axis, not distance from the origin, I guess.

Comment: What do you man by amplitude?

Comment: I'm an engineer, amplitude and modulus are synonymous to me. I would use phase...

Comment: @copper.hat I just realized that myself. Strange wording. I just took it for granted. Perhaps I shouldn't've.

Comment: Yeah perhaps the book could imply that 'amplitude' is the 'argument' of complex number, otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks anyways, I got the answer by taking the tangent thanks @Arthur

Answer (score 2):

What shape is formed by taking points in the plane that are equidistant from a  point (in this case $(3,0)$) and a line (in this case the imaginary axis)?

Note that there are points of arbitrarily large amplitude that satisfy this
equation, but only one point of minimum amplitude.

Note that I am assuming that amplitude means the modulus or length. This is
fairly standard nomenclature.

Comment: A parabola I guess.

Comment: @Siddharth: Good guess.